# Firebase Auth Handler - How to change myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler to mydomain.com/__/auth/handler?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to change the auth handler url that will be shown when using Authentication methods of Firebase?

Say, from myapp.firebaseapp.com/**/auth/handler to mydomain.com/**/auth/handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Auth domain needs to be a Firebase Hosting custom domain -- so you'd need to move `mydomain.com` to Firebase Hosting or create a new subdomain e.g. `auth.mydomain.com` that is connected to Firebase Hosting.

Once you've done that, you should add the domain as an authorized domain for Firebase Auth (as well as for any of your external OAuth provider configurations) and set the domain as `authDomain` in your `initializeApp(...)` call.

Comment: How to do that in Android sdk? It still uses firebaseapp.com and there is no place to add the custom one that was setup on Firebase through a subdomain.